# Parsing A Custom Variable Sent To PayPal

Tags: php, variables, paypal

I'd like to send a custom variable to PayPal when users make a purchase. The variable contains information the user has supplied and is being stored in the $message variable. The $product variable is just used to identify the product being purchased and create the appropriate PayPal button for that product (by referring to an array included in 'products.php'. PayPal allows you to pass it information through an input with the name "custom" as I've done below.

```
<?php
include('products.php');
$currentProduct = $_GET['product'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
?>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="<?php echo $products[$currentProduct]["paypal"]; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $message?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button paypal" value="Pay with PayPal"/>
</form>
```

However, I've looked around a fair bit and can't find an explanation for how to actually retrieve this information from PayPal once an order is completed. Could anyone please provide a simple explanation for how to go about retrieving the information found in $message once an order is completed (with or without the use of the custom PayPal variable). Thanks.

Comment: I remember doing it long time back. You have to have some other variables too sent over to the paypal. Try this 
(http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/02/17/paypal-payment-data-transfer-sample-code/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a hosted button you can't include the custom variable like this.  You'd have to include it in the advanced section of the hosted button creation wizard.  Unfortunately, it's pretty much useless there because you can't use dynamic values that way.

What you're going to have to do is go back into your button editor on PayPal and disable the "save button at PayPal" option.  This will make more fields available to your button code and custom would then work.

This isn't as secure as a hosted button, though.  As such, I would recommend you use the [Express Checkout API](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf) instead of Payments Standard.  Of course, that will require you to have experience working with web service API's in general.